# Migrate SQL Database to xConnect

Tags: xconnect, sql-database, data-exchange-framework

**Environment:** Sitecore 9.2.0 and Data Exchange Framework 3.0

I want to import the data from `SQL Database` to `xConnect` using the `Data Exchange Framework`. SQL DB has a table called Users which contains three fields i.e. Name, Address, Email. I want to import all the Users to the xConnect collection.

I have created both the endpoints i.e. `SQL` and `xConnect Client Endpoint`. But how to configure the mappings and pipelines?